# Integrate MacVim and RStudio

Tags: vimrc, macvim

I'm using MacVim, and I want to write codes for R in MacVim.
I want to have a hotkey which can:

- Send a line where the cursor is in MacVim to RStudio, execute the code in RStudio, and back a cursor to MacVim (line by line execution)
- If Visual Mode is used in MacVim, copy the chunk selected in MacVim and send it to RStudio (copy lines and paste on RStudio), execute the lines and back a cursor to MacVim (chunk execution)

Is it possible to realize this hotkey using what is prepared in Vim?

Comment: You're asking us to program your fancy idea. How about just using `"*y` and copying it to RStudio yourself.

Comment: That is what I'm doing now, so I want to speed up my coding. I know there is VimMode in RStudio, but it would be better for me to use MacVim itself. I've found similar thing can be done in GVIM ([latest comments in this discussion](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/208030898-External-VIM-editor-again-)). Same in MacVim?

Comment: It may be doable by calling some Applescript within vim which does all the steps you want to (activate RStudio, selecting textwindow, pasting, selecting some menu item from GUI, etc.). But that is terribly ugly and very slow, if you've ever seen that. Also is there no way to execute `R` from the terminal?

Comment: You can do that. If you know the command line to access rstudio (or the R compiler itself) and pass arguments for it, you can. An example  with shell : `system('expression') ` will do. You can insert the line into this expression or create a function which takes the lines and pass it to compiler or any other executable. Give dome example lines and the command line for executing in R. I am not aware whether you use MacVim within RStudio, like vrapper in eclipse. Give more details.

Comment: @SibiCoder I think `Nvim-R` does the similar thing (passing a line from Vim to R run in Terminal). I currently run MacVim and RStudio independently (just open them one by one), not MacVim in RStudio.

Comment: Can you tell me how dk you run the commands ? (The command used to run from terminal) give some screen shots or example text for better understanding

Comment: Do you mean commands to run MacVim? I use GUI version, so simply by double-clicking the icon. Since RStudio is also an app, I'm wondering whether I can use system commands (such as cmd-tab to switch from MacVim to RStudio and ctrl-v for pasting) via MacVim.

Comment: Not those. You may have commands to run a R script, may be like 'R script name'. You can directly use that command inside vim like `:system ('R script name')`

Comment: I understand. In RStudio, there are two ways to run lines. (1) In an editor in RStudio, ctrl-enter runs the line (or selected chunk). (2) copy and paste line(s) to the console in RStudio. [This video on YouTube](https://youtu.be/uwlwNRbaKMI?t=6m14s) might give you an idea of how RStudio works.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if you have `Rscript` installed, but you should have.
If you don't install R using [this tutorial](https://rud.is/b/2015/10/22/installing-r-on-os-x-100-homebrew-edition/).

Just run Terminal.app and run `Rscript` and if says "command not found", you need to install R using the terminal.

If `Rscript` now works, you can run R code directly from vim.
First copy the R code from vim (using <kbd>y</kbd>) to the unnamed register ("), which is the register vim uses, if you don't define a register. Now use the cmdline mode (with <kbd>:</kbd>) and type:

```
echo system("read arg; Rscript -e $arg", @")
```

The script should run, and the output is displayed on your screen.

Comment: The questioner would like to "[s]end a line where the cursor is in MacVim to *RStudio*".